# Convergence of $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(x\log(\lvert x\lvert ))\,dx $

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Show that the improper integral
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(x\log(\lvert x\lvert ))\,dx $$
is convergent.

I rewrote it, using even function symmetry of cosine, as twice the integral from zero to +infinity.  Now the argument of log is simply $x$, not $|x|$.

Now, to deal with $+infty$ I replace my upper limit with $R$ and will evaluate the limit as R goes to $\infty$.

There is no issue at the origin for $x\log x$, since I think by l'hopital's rule, this is viewed as a convergent sequence - converging to $0$, as $x \to 0$.  So $\cos (x\log x)$ is well-defined for all $x$.

Does anyone have any clever ideas with how to proceed?  I saw an integration by parts method on this site to show convergence of $\cos^3(x)$ (on the positive real line), so I will try this method for $\cos(x\log x)$.  If anyone has any cool tips to offer, please feel free to share :).

Thanks,

Comment: This thing oscillates like mad. I can't believe it is convergent!

Comment: Ya, me neither, @unit.  I'm currently trying to work it out with integration by parts.  I struggled similarly to show the discrete analogue to this problem was also convergent - the series of cos(nlogn) converges, but it's difficult to prove it without complex analysis methods, which I would not be allowed to use on a real variables exam...

Comment: @Unit: Actually, it is precisely because of those “mad oscillations” that it converges. See [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma).

Comment: @Lucian, I would like to try and apply the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma to the above integral - do you know whether I can directly apply the lemma ...or not quite? (I'm guessing the cos(xlogx) would be our L^1 integrable function here...) thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that it suffices to consider the convergence of

$$ \int_{1}^{\infty} \cos (x \log x) \, dx. $$

Now let $f : [1, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ by $f(x) = x \log x$. This function has an inverse $g = f^{-1}$ which is differentiable. So we have

$$ \int_{1}^{R} \cos (x \log x) \, dx
= \int_{0}^{f(R)} g'(y)\cos y \, dy
= \int_{0}^{f(R)} \frac{\cos y}{f'(g(y))} \, dy. \tag{1} $$

Notice that $f'(g(y)) = \log g(y) + 1$ is increasing and diverges to $+\infty$ as $y \to \infty$. Thus, as $R \to \infty$ it follows that (1) converges from the alternating series test.

Indeed, for large $R$ and $N = N(R) = \lfloor f(R) / \pi \rfloor$ it follows that

\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{R} \cos (x \log x) \, dx
&= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{\cos y}{f'(g(y))} \, dy + \int_{\pi N}^{f(R)} \frac{\cos y}{f'(g(y))} \, dy \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} (-1)^{k} a_{k} + \mathcal{O}(a_{N}),
\end{align*}

where $a_{k}$ is defined by

$$ a_{k} = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\cos y}{f'(g(y + k\pi))} \, dy. $$

Comment: How do you get the first equality, @sos440?  Is it just substitution / change of variable, in which case I don't follow, or is it something else you're doing, eg, integration by parts?  Thanks ...

Comment: @LebronJames, It is a consequence of the change of variable $y = f(x) = x\log x$, or equivalently, $x = g(y)$.

Comment: Do we know g(y) explicitly?

Comment: I actually follow most of your arguments now.  But I just want to know whether we can actually solve for g(y) explicitly, so that we know log(g(y)) + 1 is actually an increasing function ... thanks @sos440

Comment: @LebronJames, if you introduce Lambert-W function then you can write down $g$ explicitly. But even without knowing this, we know from inverse function theorem that $g' > 0$ and $g(y) \to \infty$ as $y \to \infty$.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much for this cool solution, @sos440 :)

Answer (score 2):

So far everything you did was correct.

I think you should consider a different approach to this question. As far as I can tell there is no closed form to this integral, but you said you just need to show that the integral is convergent.

Don't evaluate it. Do you know other ways of showing that an integral converges?